# ChartJS: How to show all duplicate labels in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

It seems that a simple bar graph in **chartjs** does not show duplicate labels. It kind of messes the graph. Check below Image.

[image]

I was wondering if I can show all labels even if it has duplicates. Is this possible with the simple bar graph? Not stacked.

Here is a sample code:

```
var MONTHS = ["January", "January", "April", "April", "May", "June"];
var dataset = [{
  label: "Test",
  type: 'bar',
  backgroundColor: barBgColor,
  borderColor: barBorderColor,
  borderWidth: 1,
  data: [1,2,3,4,3,5] 
}];

var barChartData = {
  labels: MONTHS,
  datasets: dataset
};

var barOptions = {
  borderWidth: 2,
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: chart_data.dataset.label + ' Chart'
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: chart_data.unit,
        fontStyle: "italic"
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  }
}

this.graph = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: barChartData,
  options: barOptions
});
```

Comment: What is the reason for this ? You will probably be able to tweak chart.js to achieve this but why ?

Comment: I have a set of data that will probably have the same label (e.g. date). I can use a stacked bar chart or another chart. I can also just get the latest data within a single date. I just want to know if and how I can tweak chartjs to achieve what I asked using the simple bar graph.